# Is it possible to inherit a parent class instance attribute directly into a child class instance in Python?

Tags: python, class, inheritance

Here is the code that I have put together so far (and I understand why it does not work), but it illustrates what I am trying to achieve.  First there is one parent class and multiple child classes (two shown) that inherit from the parent class:

```
class FruitClass(object):
    def __init__(self,fruit):
        self.fruit = fruit

    def method(self):
        print(f'{self.colour} {self.fruit}')

class Fruit1(FruitClass):
    def __init__(self,colour):
        self.colour = colour

class Fruit2(FruitClass):
    def __init__(self,colour):
        self.colour = colour
```

I then want to set the parent class attribute when instantiating the class and then use that specific attribute when calling parent class methods from the child classes.  In the below example, I want to get `fruit1.method()` to print out `'Green Apple'`.  However, this is not working because the attribute is an attribute of the instance rather than the class itself. Is that correct?  Further, I want to avoid having to pass in the attribute through the child function i.e. by instantiating the `Fruit1` class instance with both `'Green'` and `'Apple'` parameters, since I have a lot of child classes and do not want to have to do this every time.  Is this possible to do in a simple way?

```
fruit_class = FruitClass('Apple')
fruit1 = Fruit1('Green')
fruit2 = Fruit2('Red')
    
fruit1.method()
>>> AttributeError: 'Fruit1' object has no attribute 'fruit'
```

---

Update to better explain the use case here.  I want a parent class with a method that the child classes can all access.  But the variable in that method needs to vary depending on an external variable that I want to pass into the parent class.  So my thought is to instantiate the parent class with that variable, thus affecting the way the method works and then instantiate all the classes relative to that specific parent class.

Other than that I guess an approach would be to create a completely separate parent class with a different method and store this in a separate module, but that would include all the same child classes as were deployed for the first module (and this feels like too much repitition).  Plus then I would have to actively choose which module to import the child classes from when deploying the larger package (and I want to avoid that).

It is also specifically important that this variable be passed into the parent class, since it is not a simple choice of a or b.  It will depend on what is happening in other areas of the package.

I hope that makes more sense.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you want to do. If `FruitClass` has no attribute `color`, you can't access its attribute `color`. If you want, you could inherit `FruitClass` to create `ColoredFruitClass` that also has the `color` attribute, and then inherit _that_ class in `Fruit1` and `Fruit2`

Comment: You seem to expect your `fruit1` and `fruit2` to inherit from *a specific instance* of `FruitClass` (rather than the class itself), and furthermore to do this without you even mentioning the specific instance to inherit from.  This is simply not how classes in Python work.

Comment: But you seem to have misunderstood the point of classes -- An instance method should only ever have to deal with information that is accessible to that instance. If `FruitClass` objects aren't guaranteed to have a `color` property, then `FruitClass.method()` has no business printing `color`.

Comment: Yes jasonharper, that is a fair comment.  The fact is I want to be able to vary the fruit attribute in the parent class and then run all child classes with that attribute in them as if to run FruitClass.Fruit1('Green') so that the resuting class instance would automatically have the earlier instatiated fruit attribute (that I want to vary).  Perhaps deploying classes is not the right approach here though.

Comment: Another way of putting it @JasonHarper is I do want a set of child classes to inherit from a specific instance of the parent class.  If that is not possible at all, is there a way to generate that kind of functionality via another approach that does not involve passing the attriubte into all the child classes one by one at the time of instantiation.  I want them all to share that attribute.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you want a *[class factory](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/class-factories-a-powerful-pattern-in-python/)*.

```
def make_fruit_class(fruit):
    class FruitClass:
        def __init__(self, color):
            self.fruit = fruit
            self.color = color

        def method(self):
            print(f"{self.color} {self.fruit}")

    return FruitClass
```

Then, you can create a class for any fruit like so:

```
BananaFruit = make_fruit_class("banana")
AppleFruit = make_fruit_class("apple")
```

And, you can instantiate objects of these classes:

```
yellow_banana = BananaFruit("yellow")
green_banana = BananaFruit("green")

red_apple = AppleFruit("red")
green_apple = AppleFruit("green")
```

And, call their methods:

```
yellow_banana.method() # yellow banana
green_banana.method() # green banana

red_apple.method() # red apple
green_apple.method() # green apple
```

---

Re.

> Each child class has a variety of different init parameters, not just one colour parameter. It just to happens to be guaranteed that one common parameter amongst them

In this case, you could simply inherit from the class that was created by the factory.

```
class EdibleBanana(BananaFruit):
    def __init__(self, color, who_can_eat):
        super().__init__(color)
        self.who_can_eat = who_can_eat

    def info(self):
        super().method()
        print("Eaten by: ")
        print("\t", self.who_can_eat)

class PoisonousBanana(BananaFruit):
    def __init__(self, color, poisonous_to):
        super().__init__(color)
        self.poisonous_to = poisonous_to

    def info(self):
        super().method()
        print("Poisonous to: ")
        print("\t", self.poisonous_to)

class MagicalApple(AppleFruit):
    def __init__(self, color, powers):
        super().__init__(color)
        self.powers = powers

    def info(self):
        super().method()
        print("Magical powers: ")
        print("\t", self.powers)
        

eb = EdibleBanana("yellow", ["humans", "monkeys", "chimps"])
pb = PoisonousBanana("green", ["snakes", "cats", "tigers"])
ma = MagicalApple("red", ["gives you wings", "makes you immortal"])

eb.info()
print("")
pb.info()
print("")
ma.info()
```

which gives:

```
yellow banana
Eaten by: 
     ['humans', 'monkeys', 'chimps']

green banana
Poisonous to: 
     ['snakes', 'cats', 'tigers']

red apple
Magical powers: 
     ['gives you wings', 'makes you immortal']
```

Comment: Each child class has a variety of different init parameters, not just one colour parameter.  It just to happens to be guaranteed that one common parameter amongst them.  Tried to keep the question as simple as possible, but perhaps that is important information.

Comment: @agftrading could you add some more detail such as what these parameters might be?

Comment: Sure, give me a little time (might need a while) and I can flesh out the question, including how I have solved it, but in a way that feels like too much of a hack and not very pythonic.  It might also help illustrate exactly what I am trying to achieve.  Unless anyone gets it and has a solution in the meantime, shall be back!

Comment: @agftrading does my edit look like something that you want and make sense to you?

Comment: See https://rhettinger.wordpress.com/2011/05/26/super-considered-super/ for advice on using `super` with `__init__`.

Comment: Thanks for your efforts @PranavHosangadi.  I shall look in more detail later on, but I shall definitely be back to follow up.  Thanks.